# Updating vector values while iterating over vector in for each loop

Tags: c++, vector, foreach

This is a leetcode problem's solution where we have to find greatest sum divisible by 3 from a given array https://leetcode.com/problems/greatest-sum-divisible-by-three/. While iterating over the vector in second foreach loop what's the usage of `vector<int>(t1)`. I was trying to iterate over the vector by `for(int j : t1)` but it's giving incorrect results while the other approach gives correct result.

```
public:
    int maxSumDivThree(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<int> t1(3);
        for(int a : nums){
            //for(int j : t1){
            for(int j: vector<int>(t1)){
                t1[(a+j)%3] = max(t1[(a+j)%3], a+j);
            }
        }
        return t1[0];
    }
};
```

Comment: `for(int j: vector<int>(t1))` makes a temporary copy of t1 in the loop over which is iterated. The temporary copy `vector<int>(t1)` contains the values of the previous iteration of the outer loop (or the fresh vector with `0`s in the first iteration) while the inner loop is writing back to `t1`.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat: What would you suggest? better variable names, comments or adding few more steps in between?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes. :-)

Comment: In ancient times, it was an art to write most-compressed code (especially in C). This yielded best performance with least readability. Now, (30 years later) the compilers became f***ing sophisticated in optimization. Even schoolbook code can be turned into efficient output. This pays off in less maintenance effort. (Often the 2 ... 3 safed microseconds  in runtime are not worth the 3 additional weeks development you had to spent to get this running...)